# Connection Pool XPages driver JTopen iSeries/A400

Tags: jdbc, xpages, xpages-ssjs

Hello I have create my Osgi packare with this driver [JTOpen](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/) and the Wizard JDBC Driver Plug-in Wizard using the class "**com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver**" and import it into my UPDATESITE.NSF database on server.

All work correctly and well...
I have create under WebContent\WEB.INF\jdbc folder a file named as400.jdbc
with this parameter

```
    <jdbc type="simple">
    <driver>com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:as400://192.168.x.x;naming=system;errors=full</url>
    <user>usernameas400/user>
    <password>pwdas400</password>

<simple>
    <minPoolSize>10</minPoolSize>
    <maxPoolSize>20</maxPoolSize>
    <maxConnectionSize>200</maxConnectionSize>
    <useTimeout>1</useTimeout>
    <idleTimeout>00</idleTimeout>
    <maxLiveTime>00</maxLiveTime>
    <acquireTimeout>10000</acquireTimeout>
</simple>       
</jdbc>
```

Now in my XPages I have insert the control

```
<xe:jdbcConnectionManager id="jdbcConnectionManager1"
        connectionName="as400">
    </xe:jdbcConnectionManager>
```

And every datasource use it for the access..for example

```
                <xe:jdbcQuery var="dsas400"
                    connectionManager="jdbcConnectionManager1"
                    sqlQuery="SELECT * FROM HSTEST.TESTTABLE"
                    clearOnRendering="true" scope="view"
                    ignoreRequestParams="true">

                </xe:jdbcQuery>
            </xp:this.data>
```

And I use the @Formulas SSJS function:

```
var res = @JdbcExecuteQuery("as400", "SELECT * FROM TABLE2");
```

All work correctly and I see the DB2-iseries data..but how can I be sure you use the connection pooling feature everywhere??
what is the correct way?

Comment: I believe that connection pooling is built into the relational controls of the extension library. As long as you get your connection using what is provided, either java or SSJS, then you get that for free.  Since you are using the SSJS ext lib controls, I think you are good.

Comment: @Steve Zavocki I am doubtful , because it seems not so in reality .
there is no documentation about the connection pool I 'd like someone to explain to me a bit ' better. By monitoring the connections on iSeries seems that there is a connection pool active ... I use the 9.01FP4 with EXTLIB 9.0.1v13

Comment: I understand, you need to be sure. The basis for my comment is in this video posted on openNTF: https://youtu.be/p6oRCsTsVqc